# Changing Background color using jquery animate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, background-color

I have the following html code: `

```
<html> 
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({
      backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    });
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

</body>
</html>`
```

But I am unable to chnage the background color as mentioned using animate.
Please let me know what is wrong?

Thanks
Smitha

Answer (score 10):

For supporting background color changes you need to include either jQuery UI or jQuery color libraries

[From Docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)

> For example, width, height, or left can be animated but
>   background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("div").animate({
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [jQuery UI](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r8C6n/)
Demo: [jQuery Color](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7T73S/)

So add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and it turns out it was more effective to use add/remove classes with JS and add CSS3 transition inside them to have my color transition:

```
CSS
.firstColor{
background-color: #000000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.secondColor{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

JS

if (your condition) {
    $("#yourID").removeClass('secondColor').addClass('firstColor');
}
else{
    $("#yourID").removeClass('firstColor').addClass('secondColor');
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Question is about how to change background color using `animate` method. Adding/removing class is an alternative for getting the same result, but not the goal.